# Cannot find fatal error in vector use

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have been trying to read two numbers as string, convert them into int vectors, then add them for my lab at school. I have run my code to find this error:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: C:\windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll File: c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xstring
>   Line: 1681
>
> Expression: vector subscript out of range
>
> For more information on how your program can cause an assertion
>   failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
>
> (Press Retry to debug the application)

I have tried retrying but it opens up another dialog box that says the debug reached a breakpoint, at which point I could not continue debugging. Here is my code for those of you interested (Microsoft Visual Studio Compiler):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void input(string &largeString1, string &largeString2);
void convert(string largeString1, string largeString2, vector<int> &largeInt1, vector<int> &largeInt2);
int asciiToInt(char ch);
void add(vector<int> largeInt1, vector<int> largeInt2, vector<int> &finalInt);
void output(const vector<int> finalInt);

int main()
{
    string largeString1;
    string largeString2;
    vector<int> largeInt1(12, 0);
    vector<int> largeInt2(12, 0);
    vector<int> finalInt(13, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        input(largeString1, largeString2);
        convert(largeString1, largeString2, largeInt1, largeInt2);
        add(largeInt1, largeInt2, finalInt);
        output(finalInt);
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
void input(string &largeString1, string &largeString2)
{
    cout << "Input:" << endl << endl;
    cin >> largeString1;
    cin >> largeString2;
}
void convert(string largeString1, string largeString2, vector<int> &largeInt1, vector<int> &largeInt2)
{
    int size1 = size(largeString1);
    int size2 = size(largeString2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        int dynamicsize1 = size1 - i;
        largeInt1[11 - i] = asciiToInt(largeString1[dynamicsize1 ]);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
    {
        int dynamicsize2 = size2 - j;
        largeInt2[11 - j] = asciiToInt(largeString2[dynamicsize2 ]);
    }
}
int asciiToInt(char ch)
{
    return (ch - '0');
}
void add(vector<int> largeInt1, vector<int> largeInt2, vector<int> &finalInt)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        finalInt[12 - i] = largeInt1[11 - i] + largeInt2[11 - i];
    }
}
void output(const vector<int> finalInt)
{
    cout << endl << "Output:" << endl << endl << "The sum is: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        cout << finalInt[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did the debugger say the problem is? which line?

Answer (score 1):

I believe here is the bug you are looking for:

```
void add(vector<int> largeInt1, vector<int> largeInt2, vector<int> &finalInt)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        finalInt[12 - i] = largeInt1[11 - i] + largeInt2[11 - i];
    }
}
```

Note that `largeInt1` and `largeInt2` are of size 12. However when `i` reaches 12 you get -1 index

```
finalInt[0] = largeInt1[-1] + largeInt2[-1];
```